# what is the best method to count a *real & full* text height in block of html code?

Tags: php, html

I need to count text height in html block. So i will know is this block overflows screen or not (for example). All i have is just html code taken from database. Of course it can or can't have br's, p's or div's, so counting it is not a good idea. Also the styles can change their attributes. I need to do this on server side on PHP.
Anyone has do this already?

The solution can be in 10% not accurate - its OK.

Thank you, 
Sergey

Comment: You've answered your own question - it's impossible, because of styling, browser settings, user's screen resolution and a dozen other things. Only possible way is to render that text in a browser, than check out containing element's height.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why make things so complicated? Rather mention your higher goal, what you are trying to accomplish or what problem are you trying to solve.. We can definitely help you with some alternatives..

Comment: Well, i know the things will be not accurate, it is not a real problem, just 'as is asked' for my own professional profit. I know about counting height on client side, but i want to count it on server side. Maybe i have some intellectual CMS wich can change content block floating/position by the needs of containing it text (for example)

Comment: Well, simply put, this is not possible in the reasonable matter = impossible! You probably have the fixed line-height on the client side and you want to limit the characters amount while posting on the back-end side. Well, on the back-end side, it is still easier to use jQuery to do this.. And much easier to use jQuery or wordwrap related functions in any language, to limit the characters.. So basically, what do you want a inaccurate solution, when you can get a much better and accurate solution?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't answer that in abstract: web sites are not still pictures, they are complex documents designed to be displayed inside very different kind of devices.

You *might* be able to find an answer if you pick a concrete scenario: a given HTML+CSS rendering engine plus a certain set of configuration options (available fonts, font renderer settings, viewport size and resolution...). That is to say, you basically have to send the document to an browser and either grab a screenshot and analyse it yourself or make the browser send you back the information.

There *are* HTML engines designed for off-screen rendering: I can think of [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which is a tool to convert HTML to PDF using webkit. The question is whether you actually need one.

IMHO, your best chance is to send your document to a real desktop browser and write some JavaScript code to gather and send back the information.

Comment: Well, that is what am doing now... But the things is calculated on special machine, not clients computer.